# in R - for all TRUE, are all subsequent cols TRUE?

Tags: r, dataframe

In R:
I have a data frame of logicals, and I want to know for each row, for all values that are TRUE, where all subsequent columns are also TRUE, in which column does the first TRUE appear.

example data frame:

```
T1<-c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
T2<- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
T3<- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
T4<- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
test_df<- as.data.frame(cbind(T1,T2,T3,T4))
test_df
```

looks like:

```
     T1      T2     T3      T4
1   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
3   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
4   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE
```

since I also want to know about the last column, need to add a null column at the end

```
test_df$null_col<-TRUE
```

looks like:

```
    T1      T2      T3      T4      null_col
1   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
2   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    TRUE
3   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
4   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
```

for each row, where TRUE, and all subsequent columns are true, return the col name for that row 
How do I approach this? My first instinct is to first create a second data frame of logicals such that the first function returns TRUE only if all subsequent (cols to the right) are TRUE, and then a second function to find the column value for each row: first the second logicals data frame

```
    T1      T2      T3      T4      
1   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   
2   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    
3   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    
4   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE
```

Then the second function returns a col value for each row, either as a named list or a data frame with row numbers intact:

```
1     NA
2     T4
3     T1
4     T3
```

Comment: Why is your expected result for row 2 `NA` and not `T4` ?

Comment: an oversight SymbolixAU! not wanted in my actual answer, but helpful in this example I think. I will edit for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create an expression with `max.col` to get the position index of the first column which is TRUE in each row. To correct for cases where there are no `TRUE`s in a rows, use `rowSums` to create another expression for changing to `NA`

```
 names(test_df)[max.col(test_df, 'first') * NA^(!rowSums(test_df))]
```

Comment: I can honestly say I've never tried `NA^`*anything*. Interesting technique.

Answer (score 2):

If `m` is any of the outputs shown below then we can compute the desired vector using:

```
names(DF)[apply(m, 1, match, x = TRUE)]
## [1] NA   NA   "T1" "T3"
```

**1) rollapply** Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end transpose it and then for each column in the transposed object apply `all` to the 4, 3, 2 and 1 last positions using `rollappply`.  Then transpose back giving the matrix shown below.

```
library(zoo)

t(rollapply(t(DF), ncol(DF):1, all, align = "left"))
##    [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
## 1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## 2 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## 3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
## 4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

**2) cumprod**  Apply `cumprod` to each row in reverse order then reverse back and convert 0/1 to FALSE/TRUE.  The returned matrix is shown.  This only uses base R.

```
nc <- ncol(DF)
t(apply(DF[nc:1], 1, cumprod))[, nc:1] == 1
##      T1    T2    T3    T4
## 1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## 2 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## 3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
## 4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

**3) Reduce**  Use Reduce with `&` on the `DF` with each row reversed and then reverse back.  This only uses base R.

```
nc <- ncol(DF)
do.call("cbind", Reduce(`&`, DF[nc:1], acc = TRUE))[, nc:1]
##       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
## [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
## [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "T1      T2      T3      T4      
1   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   
2   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   
3   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    
4   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp) approach that would provide the intended results according to the comments:

```
test_df = data.frame(T1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
                     T2 = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
                     T3 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),
                     T4 = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))

test_df

Rcpp::cppFunction('
CharacterVector all_T(LogicalMatrix x) {
  CharacterVector col_names = colnames(x);
  CharacterVector out(x.nrow(), col_names(0));

  for (int i = 0; i < x.nrow(); i++){
    for (int j = x.ncol() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
      if (!x(i, j)){
        if (j == x.ncol() - 1) {
          out(i) = NA_STRING;
          } else {
            out(i) = col_names(j + 1);
          }
          break;
          }
      }
    }
  return(out);
}
                  ')

all_T(as.matrix(test_df))

#[1] NA   "T4" "T1" "T3"
```

If instead your rule is that if it goes from `T -> F -> T` that this should return `NA` for the rule, here's something derivative of @akrun's approach:

```
max_col = max.col(test_df, ties.method = 'first')
new_col = names(test_df)[max_col] 
new_col[length(test_df) + 1L - max_col != rowSums(test_df)] = NA_character_

new_col
#[1] NA   NA   "T1" "T3"
```